# After extending NEWS with a new date field, how can I list from this news field

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I have extended NEWS with a new date field (eventStartDate) and I would like to list all news with this date greater than X.

At this moment,  the WHERE clause checks tx_news_domain_model_news.datetime not my new field tx_news_domain_model_news.eventStartDate.

This is what I get

```
 whereClause => '(tx_news_domain_model_news.datetime >= '1551200578' 
 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.pid IN ('123456')) 
 AND (tx_news_domain_model_news.type='Tx_SLNewsExtended_News')'
```

This is what I would like

```
 whereClause => '(tx_news_domain_model_news.eventStartDate>= '1551200578' 
 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.pid IN ('123456')) 
 AND (tx_news_domain_model_news.type='Tx_SLNewsExtended_News')'
```

I set

```
settings.datefield = eventStartDate
```

with no effect.

I'im using NEWS 6.3 with TYPO3 7.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returns empty string in NEWS 6.3

```
public function getDateField()
{
    if (empty($this->dateField) || in_array($this->dateField, ['datetime', 'archive'])) {
        return $this->dateField;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Ok with NEWS 7.0

```
public function getDateField()
{
    if (in_array($this->dateField, ['datetime', 'archive'])
        || isset($GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_news']['columns'][$this->dateField])) {
        return $this->dateField;
    }
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it fails because of the TCA check, see https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Classes/Domain/Model/Dto/NewsDemand.php#L556-L558

so the field must be written `event_start_date`.

Comment: in 6.3 getDateField is `public function getDateField()
    {
        if (empty($this->dateField) || in_array($this->dateField, ['datetime', 'archive'])) {
            return $this->dateField;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }`